# How to use VBA to find a cell, reference another cell, and delete rows with the same text

Tags: excel, vba

Im looking for some assistance in writing a VBA script that will look for a specific value (" 0;") in column D, then add a variable for the value in column B, then finally deleting all the rows with the same variable name.  This will have to be in some type of loop so it can keep looking for the value in column D and deleting the necessary rows.  My current code is as follows:

```
Dim findingDetail As Range
Dim serviceFinding As Range
Dim strText As String

For Each findingDetail In Range("D:D")
    If findingDetail.Value = " 0;" Then

          Dim strText As String
            strText = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Select
            For Each serviceFinding In Range("B:B")
            cell.EntireRow.Delete
            Next serviceFinding
            
    End If
Next findingDetail
```

[Attached here is a screen grab of what I am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeTWH.png)

Comment: So find " 0;" in ```D``` look at that row's ```B``` and then delete every row that has the value from ```B```?

Comment: @Warcupine correct, and loop it through since " 0;" will be found more than once.

Comment: @Warcupine did you take down your solution?  I do not see it anymore.